# Compare current time with Time() function in access

Tags: time, comparison, ms-access-2010

actually i'm very new in Microsoft access 2010. i have one software which communicating with the Microsoft Access. it just send one line of command to ms access and access will execute. for example for comparison of date i'm using below command:

Arrival_Date like Date()

the access execute this command properly and it compare the Arrival_Date with the current date.
 
now i want to compare the current time which is return form Time() function with the Arrival_time.
i want to check whether the current time is within the Arrival_Time - 30second and Arrival_Time + 30second.
what command should i use to do this comparison in ms access.
appreciate your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
WHERE ArrivalTime BETWEEN Dateadd("s",-30,Time()) AND Dateadd("s",30,Time())
```

More info: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/dateadd-function-HA001228810.aspx

Comment: thanks for your replay. but it does not work. actually my Arrival_Time value format is for example 2:35:40 PM and its data type is Date&Time. is it correct or i have to change my Arrival_Time Format?

Comment: It should not make any difference. But 30 seconds +/- from now is a very short interval. Are you sure you have data to test?